# Multiple Contact Us forms and how to handle them

Tags: forms, information-architecture, organization, sitemap, contact-us

What is the best approach to organize multiple forms? Simple websites might only have 1 contact form for any type of questions.

However, some sites have contact forms for difference users. For example, Media Inquiries, Business vs Customer issues, Charity Program causes, Careers applications, etc.

How do you organize all these contact forms?

Answer (score 2):

**Most Fields are the Same**

I'm assuming all the contact forms share the same fields (like Name, Email, etc.) except for the destination (like Media Inq, Business Inq, etc.)

If this is the case, I'd recommend using the same form and one of the fields would be something like "In Regards To" and it'd be a selection of the different departments or categories.

The basic form could live on a generic page where the user would have to select where to direct the inquiry. If a "Contact Us" link was clicked on a Media page, for example, the form would load with the "In Regards To" field pre-filled with Media.

**Unique Fields Per Form**

If the fields are different for each destination, I'd recommend using a multi-step form. The first question would be something like "In Regards To" and that would determine the fields shown in the second step.

Of note, if you go this route you may also consider putting Name/Email in the first step as well. That way if users jump ship after filling out Step 1, you can at least capture their Name and Email for retargeting. (Be kind with retargeting though)

Comment: I like the multi-step approach and unifying forms into one page. However, I've seen many many sites dedicating distinct pages per form type. For example, a job position with embedded application form, a news&press with embedded media contact form, etc... It can certainly be helpful to have the correct form when needed and targeted to right audience. Have you seen any studies comparing this approach vs unifying all in one page?

Comment: For sure, a unique form with only what is needed and nothing of what is not needed would be preferred. My answer was primarily from a UX + Dev perspective (i.e. biggest bang for the buck). And no, unfortunately I don't know of any studies specifically about this question.

Answer (score 1):

**What’s the main goal of your site?**

If you want to get users to take a specific action, then designing persuasive call-to-action buttons is critical.
Whether you’re using them on pricing pages, product pages, landing pages, or your blog, well-designed CTA buttons are going to help you get more people to do what you want them to do.

If you need to offer multiple CTAs

Sometimes you’ll have to include more than one CTA button on a webpage. For example, your homepage might have one button for signing up, and another button for signing in.

If you need to offer the user multiple things they can do, you should still guide them to the thing they should do — the most important task on the page.

Persuasive CTA buttons are prioritized. Use visual hierarchy to give weight to the most important conversion pathway. Your main CTA should always be the most visually striking while the others should be less attention grabbing.

Answer (score 1):

Typeform seems to have perfected many facets of form filling usage, including multi-especially the transitions between steps. I believe trying out their design may provide you with inspiration. 
https://www.typeform.com/

I am not affiliated with them.